# Why CDK fails to deploy with an error: Syntax errors in policy error?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

We currently want to run some codes to build a tarball, then deploy the tarball using curls. Not sure if my approach is correct, however i got this error and stuck with it:

> Resource handler returned message: "Syntax errors in policy. (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 2c0ead32-b1d6-42b7-ba8b-e252bcce3657)" (RequestToken: 25adc60c-1869-6e03-44db-ddb04decf3e6, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

[image]

My code:

```
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  ... // this went fine
});

const tarballBucket = new Bucket(this, 'TarballBucket', {
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
});

const buildStep = new CodeBuildStep('Build', {
  input,
  env: {
    TARBALL_BUCKET_NAME: tarballBucket.bucketName
  },
  commands: [
    ...// some shell codes here
    'tar --exclude=".git" --exclude="node_modules" -zcvf tarball.tgz ../view-resources/*',
    'echo "uploading tarball to s3..."',
    'aws s3 cp tarball.tgz s3://$TARBALL_BUCKET_NAME/tarball.tgz'
  ],
});

// add build step to pipeline
pipeline.addStage(buildStage, {
  post: [buildStep],
});


const deployStep = new CodeBuildStep('Deploy', {
  buildEnvironment: {
    environmentVariables: {
      JWT: {
        type: BuildEnvironmentVariableType.SECRETS_MANAGER,
        value: jwtValue,
      }
    }
  },
  commands: [
    `aws s3 cp s3://${tarballBucket.bucketName}}/tarball.tgz tarball.tgz`,
    'echo "Deploying to CMS"',
    // print the tarball size in bytes
    'du -b tarball.tgz',
});

// without this buildpipeline, cdk synth complains
pipeline.buildPipeline();
tarballBucket.grantReadWrite(buildStep);
tarballBucket.grantRead(deployStep);
```

I also tried to create a role that has access to the bucket, and pass the role to the codebuild steps. But the same error occurs.

Updates: The problem is somehow with the deployStep, i commented out the deploy step and it works, the tarball is created correctly.

The buildStep works with these codes:

```
const tarballBucketRole = new Role(this, 'TarballBucketRole', {
  assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('codebuild.amazonaws.com'),
});

tarballBucket.grantReadWrite(tarballBucketRole);
const buildStep = new CodeBuildStep('Build', {
  input,
  role: tarballBucketRole,
  env: {
    TARBALL_BUCKET_NAME: tarballBucket.bucketName
  },
  commands: [
    ...// some shell codes here
    'tar --exclude=".git" --exclude="node_modules" -zcvf tarball.tgz ../view-resources/*',
    'echo "uploading tarball to s3..."',
    'aws s3 cp tarball.tgz s3://$TARBALL_BUCKET_NAME/tarball.tgz'
  ],
});
```

I deployed a solution using the role as an input to the codebuildstep and it throws the "Syntax errors in policy" again.
Same errors were thrown also with using CodePipelineSource.s3 as an input for the CodeBuildStep:

```
const tarballBucketInput = CodePipelineSource.s3(tarballBucket, 'tarball.tgz');
const deployStep = new CodeBuildStep('Deploy', {
  input: tarballBucketInput,
  commands: [
    'echo "Deploying to CMS"',
    // print the tarball size in bytes
    'du -b tarball.tgz',
});
```

Comment: Some updates:
The problem is somehow with the deployStep, i commented out the deploy step and it works, the tarball is created correctly.

Comment: Where is `jwtValue` defined? What is its value?

Comment: It's defined elsewhere, it's a secret's name.

Comment: Go to the cloudformation console and see which specific resource failed creation and triggered this error. Then look at the template and find the resource definition there (an IAM policy) and add it to the quesiton.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that your `buildStep` is not an `IGrantable` object since `CodeBuildStep` is an L3 Construct.

The method `grant*` requires an identity of `IGrantable` type.

> IGrantable: Any object that has an associated principal that a permission can be granted to. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/permissions.html#permissions_grants

`CodeBuildStep` already creates a default IAM role. If you want to use the `s3.Bucket.grant*` methods, you can use either of these two:

```
// actionRole: Custom IAM role created by CodeBuildStep
tarballBucket.grantReadWrite(buildStep.actionRole);
tarballBucket.grantRead(deployStep.actionRole);

// grantPrincipal: The CodeBuild Project's principal.
tarballBucket.grantReadWrite(buildStep.grantPrincipal);
tarballBucket.grantRead(deployStep.grantPrincipal);
```

Comment: `IGrantable` just requires having a `grantPrincipal` property of `IPrincipal` type, which `CodeBuildStep` has, so this should not be an issue.

Comment: Basically what I explained in my answer, but you need to pass the correct object to the `grant*` method. If you see OP's sample code: `tarballBucket.grantReadWrite(buildStep);` `buildStep` was passed in the `grant*` method which is not an `IGrantable`.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my comment - I am saying that to be an `IGrantable`, an object has to have `grantPrincipal` prop of type `IPrincipal`, which `CodeBuildStep` does, so it will work. This is not the cause of the issue here.